# Check if a parent exist in a database - Firebase Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to check if a parent exists or not in the Live Database, on Firebase using Javascript.

I know how to check if a exists, but not a parent. My use case is every time a user disconnect, the parent removes itself. I need to check if "**users**" parent exists.

Any ideas?

[image: Database picture of the parent I want to check]

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. Can you give a code sample of what you're trying to do (in the disconnect handler)?

Comment: As I know, if a collection becomes empty it is deleted, if you add a document to it it is created on the fly. But maybe I don't get your question

Comment: I will try to explain myself better, Basically I have a virtual world game I made, with players that can join with their nicknames. When users are trying to join, they have to insert a nickname. I want to check if the nickname they inserted is not taken already. When there are no players, the "users" parent is gone, so I can't check normally if username is equals to something in the database because it's causing troubles. So I got an idea to check if users is exist, if yes, make sure to check if the nickname is taken, if not, just continue without checking cause there are no players.

Comment: How can I check if the parent "users" is exist? Hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check if `users` exists before checking if a specific user exists. You can just ask Firebase for the value at `/users/nickname`, and check if the snapshot exists:

```
const userNameRef = firebase.database().ref('/users/nickname')
userNameRef.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
  console.log(snapshot.exists());
});
```

---

Since you also want to update the nickname based on its non-existence, you'll actually want to use a transaction for that:

```
userNameRef.transaction((currentValue) => {
  if (currentValue) return; // user already exists, abort the transaction

  return 'JSON you want to store'; // this will create the node
});
```

In this case, you'll also want to set up security rules that are enforced on the database server to never allow a user to overwrite en existing node:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$nickname": {
        ".write": "!data.exists()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```